Construct covering space with given fiber
Suppose $(X, x_0)$ has a universal cover and $A$ is a left $\pi$-set. How do I find a covering map $q: Y \to X$ with the fiber of $x_0$ isomorphic to $A$ as a $\pi$ set?
I vaguely know that this has something to do with a quotient of the universal covering by the action of a given subgroup. However, I’m a bit lost about which subgroup it should be.

Let $\tilde{p}\colon \tilde{X}\to X$ be the universal covering. For any subgroup $H$, $\tilde{X}/H\to X$ is a covering with fiber (equivariantly) isomorphic to $\pi/H$. Now if $A$ is a transitive $\pi$-set, it is (equivariantly) isomorphic to $\pi/H$ for some subgroup $H$ (to be precise, $H$ is the stabilizer of a chosen point in $A$ and is unique up to conjugacy). Hence, in this case we can find a covering with the required property.
In general, $A$ is the coproduct of transitive $\pi$-sets. In this case, we can find a collection of coverings with each covering having a fiber isomorphic to one summand of $A$ and we take the coproduct of these coverings.
